# How can I show content besides image while clicking on it and show both in a wrapper using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, show-hide

I want to show the description of the product when I click on product image and it will show gracefully with proper background but not popup. Image should be on the same place, just content should come out of background and a box should appear which will contain both image and description, I tried some code, but it is not working as required.

```
<div class="test-wrap">
    <div class="wrapper1">
        <img src="C02-06-front-png.png" alt="Nokia" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="tst">Click Here</a>
</div>


<div class="content-wrap">

    <div class="wrapper2">
        <img src="C02-06-front-png.png" alt="Nokia" />
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<style>
    .content-wrap {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        height: 250px;
        width: 400px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    .test-wrap {
        position: relative;
        height: 250px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    .content-wrap img,
    .test-wrap img {
        float: left;
    }
    .test-wrap .tst {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    .content {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
    }       
    .test-wrap .wrapper2 {
        background: yellow;
        height: 250px;
        width: 400px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tst').click(function() {
            //$('.content-wrap').show(5000);    
            var content = $('.content-wrap').html();
            $('.test-wrap').append(content);
            $('.wrapper1').remove();
            $('.tst').remove();
            $('.wrapper2').show(5000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It shows the content but quickly and not as I require. Ref. http://www.nokia.com/in-en/products/all-products/ 
That should look like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than moving HTML around and duplicating and replacing content, I'd just create the content once and hide it, then show it with an animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/FP2z9/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        var wrapper = $(this).closest(".wrapper");
        if (wrapper.hasClass("detail")){
            wrapper.removeClass("detail").animate({
                width: 161
            }, 300);
        }
        else {
            wrapper.addClass("detail").animate({
                width: 326
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Better solution...you should adopt this approach Mr. Patel.

Answer (score 1):

Cool problem...it's happening because the copied `wrapper2` isn't hidden before you start your animation. After you copy and append it, it's already visible. Just hide it first and then your animation will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tst').click(function() {
            //$('.content-wrap').show(5000);    
            var content = $('.content-wrap').html();
            $('.test-wrap').append(content);
            $('.wrapper1').remove();
            $('.tst').remove();

            // hide first..!
            $('.wrapper2').hide();
            $('.wrapper2').show(5000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Be careful though: there are now 2 `wrapper2` elements, one visible and one hidden...make sure this doesn't lead to future problems ;)

Comment: Ya, I did the same Chris, but the problem is, I want to show the image as it is while showing the content. Image should not hide. It should be there always and content should come out from the background

Comment: Hmmm...I'm unsure why the image would not be showing, but I think the best way to tackle this, rather than trying to fix your code, would be to approach it by creating the content _first_, get it looking right - then hide it an work on animating it, rather than trying to create code 'on the fly' and appending it and hoping it works correctly...make sense?